# how to apply the Animation in viewflipper in Android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I create one simple image banner apps in which I use the viewflipper for swipe image one by one. My apps run very well but the first image is repeated two time. Here I use the image array and apply in view flipper.

The Array is:

```
int imageDrawable[] = new int[]{R.drawable.advanturestorybanner_ipad_landscap,
R.drawable.femouspeopleofthebiblebanner_ipad_landscap,
R.drawable.littlebanner_ipad_landscap,
R.drawable.thechildrenbiblebanner_ipad_landscap,
R.drawable.thecomicbookbiblebanner_ipad_landscap,
R.drawable.thehandybiblebanner_ipad_landscap };

bannerImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageDrawable[j]);
```

Comment: you don't want to loop for your views?

Comment: I am giving you one good example of view flipper. Have a look at this example: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/viewflipper-animation.html Best Of Luck

Comment: yes i use in a for loop for setting background image in viewflipper